# Linking external script in VueJS webpack generated template

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, vue.js

I have a VueJS webpack generated project in which I want to link the jQuery & Bootstrap libraries. I've downloaded the sources and want to link the JS & CSS into my HTML file like so:

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

The HTML file is in the same folder than the assets folder.
My problem is that the script doesn't load and I have this error:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
None of the solutions I found for this problem leaves me satisfied, people use another file containing some sort of module declaration, but I think it's a bit overkill to have such files when it's only for linking a script file into an HTML file...

Answer (score 0):

So the index.html is in the assets folder?

Won't it just be this then:

Comment: I said "in the same folder than the assets folder", not "in the assets folder", sorry for the misunderstanding